# Does Sabre provides a way to get rich content flights

Tags: sabre

I was reading this press release "[Sabre and Routehappy collaborate to provide travel agents with intelligent and visually rich airline product content in flight search](https://www.sabre.com/insights/releases/sabre-and-routehappy-collaborate-to-provide-travel-agents-with-intelligent-and-visually-rich-airline-product-content-in-flight-search/)" in sabre website.

Is there any Sabre API endpoint to get rich content, images for the carrier, Cabin class, etc in BFM or any other air request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment there is no API with Routehappy content. You could contact your account team if you are interested in this.

Comment: Thanks, I will contact the account team.